# Creating two dimensional list not working as expected

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-2.x

I am pretty new to Python, and I have tried something similar to what I am trying here before and got the correct output, but in this case my code is not working as intended and I am not sure why. I am trying to create a two-dimensional list that has ids of documents (arbitrary numbers from a file). See code here:

```
termDocuments = []
termDocument = []
for ids in termids:
    ...
    for documentIndices in range(
            int(iitermids.index(ids)),
            int(iitermids.index(ids)+int(documentFrequencyForTerm)-1)):
        termDocument.append(docids[documentIndices])
    termDocuments.append(termDocument)
    print termDocuments[len(termDocuments)-1]
```

I know my range is pretty messy and I probably have a few style issues, but it is grabbing the correct values but not appending them correctly. I want `termDocuments` to contain something like

```
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6']]
```

but it is just appending values to the end of the list and coming out as a one-dimensional list like this:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```

I was under the assumption that appending a list to a list created a two-dimensional list.

Is this wrong?

Comment: Off-topic: `termDocuments[-1]` means the same thing as `termDocuments[len(termDocuments)-1]` and is arguably more readable (at least if you understand how negative indices work in Python).

Comment: Please provide code that is easy to follow. This means excluding all the details of your app that are superficial, like names that mean nothing in the context of this question. Just create a minimum working (or not working) code snippet, provide the inputs, show the output, and explain what you want to happen differently, or where you are confused

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing what's in `docids[documentIndices]`.

Comment: speedyturkey figured out the correct answer below. Thanks everyone

Answer (score -1, accepted):

(Edited after re-reading your code) I think your issue is that you are setting `termDocument = []` outside of your outer loop. If you move this to the top of your outer loop, it should give the desired result.

Comment: You are right. I don't know why you got downvoted. When I did this before I reset it at the end of the inner loop and it worked correctly. Thank you

Comment: My original answer was less helpful, but I am glad it works now. Please feel free to mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
list1 = []    
for i in range(10): # creating a list with nested lists
    list1.append([])
    for j in range(10):
        list1[i].append("1") # filling nested lists with ones
```

This will output a list with 10 lists in it, filled with ones.

Answer (score 0):

> but it is just appending values to the end of the list and coming out as a one-dimensional list

```py
print termDocuments[len(termDocuments)-1]
```

This is because you're printing a 1-d list for every `termid` on your last line. And as far as I know you could have only one termid within termids to begin with.

Your intuition on append is correct though

```py
>>> A = []

>>> A.append([1, 2, 3])
>>> A.append([7, 8, 9])

>>> print(A)
[[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9]]
```